# RxJS detect when observable has been subscribed to

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, observable, reactivex

I have a need to detect when an observable (`observedEvents`) has been subscribed to, and then subscribe to another observable (`triggerEvent`). I don't want to subscribe to `triggerEvent` manually, but only once and when `observedEvents` has a subscription.

Here is some code explaining what I am looking for:

```js
// This just emits events
let emitting = new EventEmitter();

// This is the main Observable which someone else might
// have access to
let observedEvents = Rx.Observable.merge(
  Rx.Observable.fromEvent(emitting, 'aba'),
  Rx.Observable.fromEvent(emitting, 'bob')
)

// This trigger should get a subscription if observedEvents
// has one, i.e. when I subscribe to observedEvents
// that subscription activates this trigger

// I have made an attempt at this by calling skipUntil
// this however skips one event, but I don't want that
let triggerEvent = Rx.Observable.merge(
  // these actions are things that can
  // happen when the trigger is active
  Rx.Observable.of('a').delay(200),
  Rx.Observable.of('b').delay(400),
  Rx.Observable.of('c').delay(600)
)
.skipUntil(observedEvents);

// Something else should be used to activate trigger
// I don't want to do this part manually
triggerEvent.subscribe(val => {
    console.log(`Do something fancy with ${val}`);
});

//----------------------------------------------------
// Somewhere else in the code...
//----------------------------------------------------
observedEvents.subscribe(evt => {
  console.log(`Some event: ${evt}`);
});
// At this point I want triggerEvent to become active
// because observedEvents has a subscription

setTimeout(() => {
  emitting.emit('bob', 'world');
  setTimeout(() => emitting.emit('aba', 'stackoverflow!'), 500);
}, 200);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.7/dist/global/Rx.umd.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/EventEmitter/5.1.0/EventEmitter.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Is this possible?

I hope that explains what I'm looking for.

As I'm writing this, I'm thinking a solution with **Subjects** is probably what I need. I'm not sure, but I just need a nudge in the right direction or a solution if possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### For rxjs > v7, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71854548/2089675)

---

#### Answer

Sure enough I was right about using Subjects. The key was the observers list for Subject. Here is what I finally did:

```js
let emitting = new EventEmitter();
let sub = new Rx.Subject();

// return this to users
let myGlobalSub = sub.merge(Rx.Observable.of(1, 2, 3));

// For internal use
let myObservers = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(emitting, 'evt');

console.log(`The number of subscribers is ${sub.observers.length}`);

// Only do something if myGlobalSub has subscribers
myObservers.subscribe(l => {
  if (sub.observers.length) { // here we check observers
    console.log(l);
  }
});

// Somewhere in the code...
emitting.emit('evt', "I don't want to see this"); // No output because no subscribers

myGlobalSub.subscribe(l => console.log(l)); // One sub

emitting.emit('evt', 'I want to see this'); // Output because of one sub

console.log(`The number of subscribers is ${sub.observers.length}`);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>

<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5.5.11/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/EventEmitter/5.2.5/EventEmitter.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `observers` is now marked as deprecated, to be internal in v. 8. Looking for a way to workaround this…

Comment: @PhiLho see this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71854548/2089675)

Answer (score 4):

The answer by @smac89 use the `observers`property which has been deprecated in RxJS 7 and is scheduled to be removed in version 8.

If you only want to know if an Observable has been subscribed to, you may use the `observed` boolean property instead.

There is currently no real equivalent to the observers array.

```js
let emitting = new EventEmitter();
let sub = new rxjs.Subject();

// return this to users
let myGlobalSub = rxjs.merge(sub,rxjs.of(1, 2, 3));

// For internal use
let myObservers = rxjs.fromEvent(emitting, 'evt');

console.log(`Has the subject been subscribed to ? ${sub.observed}`);

// Only do something if myGlobalSub has subscribers
myObservers.subscribe(l => {
  if (sub.observed) { // here we check observers
    console.log(l);
  }
});

// Somewhere in the code...
emitting.emit('evt', "I don't want to see this"); // No output because no subscribers

myGlobalSub.subscribe(l => console.log(l)); // One sub

emitting.emit('evt', 'I want to see this'); // Output because of one sub

console.log(`Has the subject been subscribed to ? ${sub.observed}`);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>

<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@%5E7/dist/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/EventEmitter/5.2.5/EventEmitter.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Added in RxJs 7.1 check your version in case you can't find it !

Comment: Thanks. Your answer has been linked for people using `rxjs > v7`

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Apparently tap already [supports this behavior](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/interface/TapObserver) natively.

Rather than creating all sorts of interlocking objects as in the accepted answer, we can do this by writing our own operator function that *only* uses existing rxjs operators! In my case I was looking for something that had the effect of `startWith` combined with `tap`; trigger some side effect as soon as a subscription occurs, but don't worry about *what* it does or returns.

Given some source observable, we'd like to do the following:

```js
const source = of(1,2,3).pipe(
  onSubscribe(() => /* some action */ console.log('observable subscribed')),
  /* your other code */
  tap({
    next: n => console.log('next ', n),
    error: e => console.log('error ', e),
    complete: () => console.log('observable complete')
  }),
);
```

If you look at [the documentation for creating an operator](https://rxjs.dev/guide/operators#creating-custom-operators), looking past all the fluff (i.e. body of the operator), you'll see that the operator is simply a function that accepts *something* and returns a function that accepts an observable (your source observable) and returns an observable.

In that case, the starting point of our operator can simply be a passthrough of the source observable since we don't want to actually modify it.

```js
onSubscribe<T>() {
  return (obs: Observable<T>) => {
    return obs;
  };
}
```

Next we need to figure out how to combine it with our callback function.

```js
// WRONG
onSubscribe<T>(callback: Function) {
  return (obs: Observable<T>) => {
    callback();
    return obs;
  };
}
```

This is problematic. If you don't subscribe to `source` here, the output will still show `"observable subscribed"`. The problem here is that `callback()` will be run during the setup phase (don't know if that's the technical term or not) before subscription has actually happened. Clearly we still have to combine it into the observable stream itself, but still get called right away. Well, `of` makes "things" happen right away (completes immediately with no value, or runs and completes immediately with a value), so we could `map` our callback off of that (note that `map` must be used instead of `tap`, otherwise the `of`'s null will work itself into the output type, and we don't want that!), and then to actually combine it with our source observable, we can use `merge`!

```js
onSubscribe<T>(callback: Function) {
  return (obs: Observable<T>) => {
    // null, or any value, is required in order to trigger the tap
    return merge(of(null).pipe(map(() => callback())), obs);
  };
}
```

Now if you don't subscribe to `source` there will not be an output until you do....except that output also includes the `null` from `of`. Let's clean that up by having `merge` `skip` the first emitted value, and we're done!

```js
onSubscribe<T>(callback: Function) {
  return (obs: Observable<T>) => {
    return merge(of(null).pipe(map(() => callback())), obs).pipe(skip(1));
  };
}
```